# Android Save spinner state in onCreate, and Activity onResume

Tags: java, android, spinner, adapter, zxing

I am currently facing 2 problems, the spinner state is not saving and when I am on the InformationActivity the spinner is reset. I have used the information on other posts but it doesnt seem to help.

At the moment I cant use `finish();` in my `onBackPressed();` on `InformationActivity` because it goes back to the `ScannerView` as I am Implementing the ZXing library. How could I save the Spinner state and also stop the program from crashing `onBackPressed` when I am on `HomeActivity`.

Thanks.

HomeActivity:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private Button buttonLogout;
    private ZXingScannerView scannerView;
    private final int permission_code = 1;

    String [] selectedProfile;

    Spinner spinner;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        }
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            spinner.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("yourSpinner", 0));
            // do this for each of your text views
        }
        else {
            //android spinner to select profile
            spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerProfiles);
            adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.restrictions, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        }

    }


    //opens camera when button is pressed
    public void scanBarcode(View view) {
        //check if user given app camera permissions
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, permission_code);

        }
        //opens camera
        scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        scannerView.setResultHandler(new ZXingScannerResultHandler());
        //stops camera and scannerview
        setContentView(scannerView);
        scannerView.startCamera();

    }

    //selects an item from the spinner and passes it to InformationActivity
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item + " Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                selectedProfile = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Wheat);
                break;
            case 1:
                selectedProfile = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Crustaceans);
                break;
            case 2:
                selectedProfile = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Eggs);
                break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }


    //stops camera and outputs barcode result to a Toast
    class ZXingScannerResultHandler implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
        @Override
        public void handleResult(Result result) {
            String resultBarcode = result.getText();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InformationActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("BarcodeString", resultBarcode.toString());
            intent.putExtra("ProfileArray", selectedProfile);
            startActivity(intent);
            scannerView.stopCamera();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == permission_code) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
        //go back to home after permissions accepted
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        scannerView.stopCamera();
    }


    //goes back to homepage when back button is pressed
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        scannerView.stopCamera();
    }

    //stops the camera on pause
    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        scannerView.stopCamera();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("yourSpinner", spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
    }

}
```

InformationActivity:

```
public class InformationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_information);

        TextView barcodeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBarcode);
        barcodeView.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("BarcodeString"));

        TextView profileView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvProfile);
        String[] selectedProfile = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("ProfileArray");
        profileView.setText(selectedProfile[0]);


    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: crash log please

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView.stopCamera()' on a null object reference

Comment: The problem here is that ScannerView and HomeActivity is the same Activity so when camera is closed and I press back it closes a null object, how Could I go around this?

Comment: scanBarcode() from where you are triggering? If scanBarcode not triggered then scannerView will be null and hence crash.

Comment: I understand, do you know how I could save the instance state of the spinner when opening and closing the activity?

Comment: Do you want to save your spinner position on OnResume() ? @KyrilKhaltesky

Comment: onRestoreInstanceState can be used in ur case

Comment: Yes, but I want to keep the position of the spinner also

Comment: Could you show me how I could implement that with my code as I cant find any documentation anywhere about this.

Comment: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Saving_and_Restoring_Activity_State_in_Android_Studio

Comment: Can you use sharedpreferences for save ?@KyrilKhaltesky

Comment: Yes but I am new to android studio and not sure how to implement sharedpreferences

Answer (score 0):

To Save Spinner posotion  in sharedpreference :

```
int userChoice = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("FileName",0);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref.edit();
prefEditor.putInt("userChoiceSpinner",usersChoice);
prefEditor.commit();
```

Get Data from sharedpreferences :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("FileName",MODE_PRIVATE);
int spinnerValue = sharedPref.getInt("userChoiceSpinner",-1);
if(spinnerValue != -1) {
  // set the selected value of the spinner 
  spinner.setSelection(spinnerValue);
}
```

Also look into this :

One Another Example to save : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29527936/8448886

SharedPreference Tutorial :https://www.journaldev.com/9412/android-shared-preferences-example-tutorial

Comment: Could you show me where I would enter that code because my current solution is not working :(

Comment: Where you are selecting Spinner put save code there and inside onResume put  GetData from sharedpreference.

Comment: That worked thanks, I have one more question... When I am on the HomeActivity and I press back the Spinner wipes out because it is in the onCreate method, is there any way I can counter that?

Comment: Welcome, @KyrilKhaltesky, Happy to help you, Sorry i'm not getting your second question.

Comment: Do you want to save scanner result @KyrilKhaltesky

Comment: So at the moment when I am on the ScannerView and press back it returns me to HomeActivity as intended but the Spinner disappears, the same also happens when I am on HomeActivity and I press back the spinner also disappears regardless if the spinnervalue is saved or not

Comment: spinner.setSelection(spinnerValue); put it on onResume();

Comment: That still wipes out all the options from the spinner, I think this is because the spinner is initiated in the onCreate and when perform onBackPressed it setContentView(R.layout.activity_home); without creating the spinnner again

Comment: Create spinner object to inside your onResume()

Answer (score 0):

when you select any item from spinner at that time get that selected item and store that position and after when you come back to activity load spinner first, compare that item with array items and get position of that item then set that position to spinner i think this way you get exact selection of that item into spinner.